# How to find the optimal number of workers for parfor?

Tags: matlab, performance, amazon-ec2, parallel-processing, parallelism-amdahl

How to find the optimal number of workers for **`parfor`** on Amazon's virtual machine?

For which cases I should use the number of the physical and for which the number of the logical cores?

Is there any "**Rule of Thumb**" for this?

I run a compiled code ( an executable code ).

Comment: I'm not sure this is an answerable question. Optimal how (Fastest run time? Cheapest deal? Minimal network traffic?)? How do you know you even need `parfor` (i.e. perhaps rewriting your algorithm would allow it to run sufficiently fast on a single core)? Do you have GPU cores available? I think the answer depends on the specific algorithm, the available hardware and the optimization objective. The only valid answer for such a general question would be "run it with different settings and find out".

Comment: Run your loop on different configuration, collect the results and decide.

Comment: With all due respect to both opinions expressed above, the problem has a solution, **without** spending ( wasting ) remarkable expenses on blind-experimentation - the meta-strategy "**run it** *( many times )* **so as to decide how to run it *COST-EFFICIENTLY*** - is *not **Free-of-Charge*** as executing such meta-strategy *will cost one **MANY** times more*, than re-running the 'optimal'-configuration once more again... won't it? Cloud "vouchers" for StartUps try to convince one to believe the opposite, but costs matter, don't they?  :o)

Answer (score 4):

[image]

> **Q** : *How to find the **optimal** number of workers for **`parfor`** on Amazon's virtual machine?*

In similarly, just partially, defined situations, I start with similar set of principal objections like those *[above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58788450/optimal-number-of-workers-for-parfor#comment103859572_58788450)* "Optimal according to what criterial function ( utility fun / penalty fun ) of what parameters and costs - **`[TIME]`** ( first, partial result's latency, E2E completion ), **`[SPACE]`** ( yesss: cache & RAM footprints ), scaling, externalities ( energy-costs, `{ owned | rented }`-infrastructure-costs, R&D-costs, design/engineering-costs, QA-costs, validation/certification-costs, other related labour-costs, costs of risk-mitigation policies - to name just a few ) ?", already raised in sentence #2 by [@Dev-iL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3372061/dev-il), retelling the wisdom of Lewis Carroll, inscribed into Alice In The Wonderlands:

> <sub>”**Alice :** Which way should I go?
>
> **Cat :** That depends on where you are going.
>
> **Alice :** I don’t know.
>
> **Cat :** Then it doesn’t matter which way you go.”</sub>

this tells us about what happens
if not having
any & all criteria ***pre***-defined:
**"*( having no target )*, any road will get you there..."**

---

### Yet, this problem was already solved, some 50-years ago :

This question was solved by Dr.Gene AMDAHL (1967), based on work of prof.Kenneth E. KNIGHT (1966) and the solution is in applying the "**Law of diminishing returns**", named after the former, Amdahl Law. For both details and for contemporary criticism of naively applied original ( overhead-naive and atomic-amounts of work ) read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3)

**Step 0 :**
test/**record** the net-time of all pure-**`[SERIAL]`**-ly executed sections of the **C**ode-**u**nder-**R**eview ( **CuR** ), that are "before" and "after" the wished-to-have `parfor`-syntax-constructor.

**Step 1 :**
test/**record** the net-time of all **`parfor`**-{ **instantiation** + **termination** }-**overhead costs**. Here take all properly-scaled parameters for call-signature and returned-values types & sizings ( The CuR has to spend some time to serialise/deserialise all of 'em on a per-call basis and has also to spend additional overhead time to SER/DES on preparing/transporting/collecting each of the "remotely"-`parfor`-ed results ), scale of MEM-allocs - that also takes remarkable amounts of time in comparison to CuR if just some "shallow"-computing-density or memory-areas' re-use inefficient parallel-CuR happens to get into consideration ). Some of these add-on overhead costs ( recorded in [TIME]-domain ) get accrued "inside" the `parfor`-decorated parts of the code ( and are invisible or do not happen during a pure-`[SERIAL]` code-execution, so test/benchmark may require some work to isolate these add-on costs "inside" the `parfor`-ed section's suspect-ops, that allocate and never re-use larger memory-areas etc, if the costs modeling strives to count down to the cents of externally paid infrastructure expenses ).

**Step 2 :**
test/**record** the atomicity-of-workunit introduced "orphaned"-time of the last-batch of workunit(s) that will never get faster (due to atomicity-of-workunit - indivisible duration of work, that no other free processor-core will help )

> *...should use the number of the **physical** and for which the number of the **logical cores**?*

**Step 3 :**
test/**record** actual work-stealing / net-own-work ratio for either of provided ( whatever these are "marketing"-labeled ) types of code-execution units ( virtual-devices bearing the most of inefficiencies due to higher latencies, higher work-stealing ratios - i.e. expect way poorer efficiencies for any form of a primarily computing-intensive parallel-workers )

**Step 4 :**
test/**record** actual frequency / cache-sizing / RAM-caused CPU-starvation conditions, that will cause the "units-of-work" actually "there"-execute poorer, than one have expected on { local-| private-grid-}-computing infrastructure.

**Step 5 :**
**compare the all-accrued-costs** for any number of cores/types under consideration, using due (and ***properly relaxed*** by all in-efficiencies recorded above ) parameters from Steps 0:4 and using price-plan(s) from any of your infrastructure providers you will get approximate costs of using more/less-resources for any given time/financial-budget constraint.

All credits go to Dr.Gene AMDAHL, whose work is hated by all marketeers selling as many as possible "cheap"-labeled yet-underperforming-and-shared-only toys (yes, virtualised means also another layer of add-on overheads and results in SHARED co-execution on silicon ( **`0.5 [ns]` cache depletions at a cost of many repeated `~350+[ns]` re-fetches of the previously already cached data again "across" the NUMA locality-boundary resulting in repetitive RAM-I/O-channels' bottlenecks** are the least loss to mention here ) - the sharing/virtualisation-introduced work-stealing of CPU-ticks will show you the amounts of stolen CPU-ticks your computing-payloads did not get to compute in favour of others, "sharing" this very same "cloudy-heaven-dream", paid by you on a "per-hour-of-use" basis, outside of your domain of control ).

Clouds may be fine for seldom running some ad-hoc, low computing-intensity ( which DSP, obviously, is not, is it? ) with minimum cross-domain communication/coordination, cohort of reasonably-sized tasks that may benefit from distributed, latency-masking, *(naive)*-brute-force execution of many such "shallow" & "not-much-demanding" work-units ( many times inefficient per-se from the point of view of HPC-grade computing ), yet the very "cheap"-(*just*)-sounding price-plans make one realise, that one's own, private infrastructure would cost ( if decided in due time, before already spending these expenses ) about the same as using the "cheaply" rented one for the second, third, ... n-th time.

> <sub>[ May ask real businesses about their costs-adjustments and real-life accountability for even the "consultants' cast" cloudy-dreams, hands-on stories exist, do not hesitate to ask :o) ]</sub>

So, the decision of your-context-formulated **optimum**-costs is yours. Always.